# Set a dynamic value to “value” attribute of a html:select tag

Tags: struts, struts-1

How can I set a dynamic value to the `value` attribute of a Struts `html:select` tag from `bean:write` to highlight the selection?

Answer (score 0):

The html select tag automatically selects the option that has a value equal to the property of the select tag. So, if your form bean has a `getFoo()` method and this method returns "bar", the following select tag will have its option with value "bar" selected:

```
<html:select property="foo">
    list of options
</html:select>
```

To make some option selected, just put its value in the property of the form bean:

```
// in the action
form.setFoo("bar");

// in the JSP
<html:select property="foo">
    list of options
</html:select>
```